# Parse a string to predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, odata, predicate

I'm trying to work out a solution, where at runtime a procedure would parse a "string" and return a predicate. so far what I've found is [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) class (sample) that does the job.

I'm wondering - is it possible to use OData lib to the same ? 
Pass in the "odata" structure string ("?color='red'&param=foo"), and get a Linq predicate ?

Comment: If you write it by yourself you can, actual DLINQ implementation doesn't accept that syntax.

Comment: what is so complicated there that you neend dynamic linq? normally dynamic linq is not necessary for string parsing.

Comment: Nothing special.. Simply looking for a best way to parse String to Predicate, and it should support such things like "(Name.StartsWith("a") Or Name.StartsWith("C")) and (Age > 24 and Age < 55)

Comment: It would help if you gave some examples of what you are trying to parse, and what kind of predicate you are expecting it to return.

Comment: I'm building a "Dynamic" contact list, that retunrs a subset of all contacts in the system. That means, that every time I request the contactlist, I can get a different set, depending on the Filter. 

The Idea is to let the user set up the filter, and save it.
So when time comes to consume the list, (retrieve filtered contacts) filter would be applied on global contact pool, and a subset returned.

So the question is - how can we store the "filter" ? 
(storing SQL string is out of the question) So we thought it would be most simple to store a string, then parse it and apply to a collection<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODataLib contrib project includes a parser similar to what you're looking for. It's doesn't produce the LINQ predicate yet, it only produces intermediate AST, but it might give you something to start from. See http://odata.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ODataLib&referringTitle=Home (the library is available as a source code on the codeplex or as a nuget package http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData.Contrib)

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser.  This is actually fairly simple if you are parsing predicates for a small number of well known types.  Generically it probably requires reflection, which makes it a bit more of a pain, but not undo-able.

I would probably parse it to some intermediate format before turning it into a predicate.  If you are doing it for a specific class, the easiest way is likely to parse it into an instance of that class, and write a comparer class that checks the non-null properties of one against the other.  YMMV.

Generically, probably parse it into a Dictionary or something like that, and write a comparer class that uses reflection on your type (which will have to be one of your params).

Comment: Well, that's kinda the whole point of "trying to us Odata". So instead of writing own libraries, to makes use of existing ones.